# Weird flags when building LLVM project with Make using the Clang Compiler

Tags: c, clang, llvm, clang++

I recently built LLVM into the following path: `C:\LLVM\llvm-new-build`. I then added this path to my Environmental Variables/Path, `C:\LLVM\llvm-new-build\Debug\bin`. I'm trying to build my LLVM project, but I'm getting some weird output from Clang:

```
clang `llvm-config --cflags` -Wall -Iincludes/ src/*.c -c src/*.c
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4146'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4180'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4244'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4258'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4267'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4291'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4345'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4351'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4355'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4456'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4457'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4458'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4459'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4503'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4624'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4722'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-wd4800'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-w14062'
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-we4238'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/DWIN32'

clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/D_WINDO
WS'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/W3'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/MP'
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

It says there are no arguments like `-wd4146` etc, but I haven't passed those to the clang compiler, and a quick google search shows know helpful answers on what these mean. This is what my build file looks like:

```
LCC = clang
LCXX = clang++

LLVM_CC_FLAGS=`llvm-config --cflags`
LLVM_LINK_FLAGS=`llvm-config --libs --cflags --ldflags core analysis executionengine jit interpreter native`

C_FLAGS = -Wall -Iincludes/
CXX_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-self-assign

SOURCES = src/*.c

all: ${SOURCES}
    ${LCC} ${LLVM_CC_FLAGS} ${C_FLAGS} ${SOURCES} -c ${SOURCES}
    ${LCXX} ${LLVM_LINK_FLAGS} *.o ${LLVM_FLAGS} -o j4
    -rm *.o
```

The output from `llvm-config --cflags`

```
-IC:/LLVM/llvm/include -IC:/LLVM/llvm-new-build/include  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
  /MP -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEP
RECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WA
RNINGS -wd4146 -wd4180 -wd4244 -wd4258 -wd4267 -wd4291 -wd4345 -wd4351 -wd4355 -
wd4456 -wd4457 -wd4458 -wd4459 -wd4503 -wd4624 -wd4722 -wd4800 -w14062 -we4238 -
D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

Comment: What do you get if you run *just* `llvm-config --cflags`?

Comment: I'll update the question at the end :)

Comment: I'm on Linux, but AFAIK `llvm-config` isn't for `clang`.

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried it with MinGW and it gives the same error.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the calls to `llvm-config`?

Comment: Kind of, it doesn't compile since I have calls to the "llvm-c/Core.h" header in my code.

Comment: Do you have `llvm-clang`? Use that instead of just `clang`.

Comment: I don't think I do have llvm-clang, I'm using the clang inside of the LLVM that I just built, which works normally. I've tried this in CMD and in Git Bash.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe someone else will have some ideas. But on Linux `clang` and `llvm-clang` are distinct and different commands (from different packages).

Comment: It's alright, thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: try removing those `unknown argument`s but keep other flags generated by `llvm-config`? btw, is "LLVM project" a project based on LLVM?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't have `llvm-clang` on Linux.

Comment: @HongxuChen I'm on a Debian derived distro. I got `llvm-clang` when I did `apt-get install llvm` (which did include `llvm-config`). `clang` was a separate package (`apt-get install clang`). Doesn't really help OP though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What's the functionality for llvm-clang? Is it a wrapper of clang specified to generate llvm bitcode? (I'm not able to try that tool myself since that tool seems packaged with clang-3.3 but my mirror only provides clang-3.4 and clang-3.5.)

Comment: @HongxuChen It appears to be a wrapper. I just ran `---version` and it's the same as `clang`. Chalk it up to odd debian packaging.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Reasonable. Thanks for your information.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use an MSVC built LLVM installation with Clang + its MinGW target. Try `clang-cl` instead. Or build LLVM with MinGW.

Comment: Hello, I'm awake. Going to try the `clang-cl` stuff, and LLVM project is a project which uses LLVM.

Comment: Okay `clang-cl` seems to get rid of the unknown argument problem, however, the "no such file or directory" stuff still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question really has several layers, so I'm going to try to break this down into three parts: a discussion of what is happening inside the backticks, the *unknown argument* errors, and the *no such file or directory* errors.

## What is `llvm-config`?

`llvm-config` is a tool for the LLVM infrastructure that gets configuration information needed to compile programs that need LLVM. So in response to the comment at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770889/weird-flags-when-building-llvm-project-with-make-using-the-clang-compiler?rq=1#comment43953816_27770889), `llvm-config` actually **is intended for use with clang** when clang is used to compile an LLVM project.

The `--cflags` option gives C compiler flags including LLVM headers, which you saw in the output to `llvm-config --cflags`. You said

> "It says there are no arguments like -wd4146 etc, but I haven't passed those to the clang compiler"

But by putting it in backticks, your shell took the output from `llvm-config --cflags` and pasted it into your original command. So you did include those arguments, you just didn't realize it!

I will also note that the output from `llvm-config` is highly dependent on your build system and the version of LLVM. For example, when installed on Ubuntu Linux 14.05, LLVM 3.5 with GNU Make and Ninja generators, the output from `llvm-config --cflags` is:

```
-I/.../llvm-3.5.0/llvm/include -I/.../llvm-3.5.0/build/include  -fPIC -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-comment -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

It noticeably doesn't include any of your offending options like `-wd4146` or `-wd4180` nor any reference to Windows or preprocessor arguments.

## What are those weird options like `/DWIN32`, `/D_WINDOWS`, `/W3`, and `/MP`?

- /D defines a preprocessing symbol for a source file, in this case WIN32 and _WINDOWS. [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx)
- /W3 directs MSVC to display level 1, level 2 and level 3 (production quality) warnings. [3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx)
- /MP causes MSVC to create multiple instances of itself and attempt to build the project in parallel. [4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx)

The problem is that they're passed to the compiler's arguments prefixed with a forward slash (notice that all other options were passed with a hyphen). As a result, your build is attempting to handle those as file names, as indicated by the resulting errors, for example:

```
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/DWIN32'
```

Why it's looking in `C:/Program Files (x86)/...` is up to some aspect of your LLVM installation and/or your operating system. I'm going to guess it's the last location in your execution path or it is your present working directory.

## What are those weird options like `-wd4146` and `-wd4180`?

Those are options to disable certain warnings emitted for MSVC. For example, *C4146* is "[unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysb0wexw.aspx)" and *C4180* is "[qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysb0wexw.aspx)"

[Here's an example](http://kaba.hilvi.org/pastel-1.4.0/cmake/SetupCompilers.cmake.htm) of doing the exact same thing, but from inside a GNU Make file instead of from the command line (look at the block beginning `if (MSVC)`)

## So why isn't my project building?

I can't answer this authoritatively without inspecting your LLVM build. However,

- **Unknown argument**: You've discovered an incompatibility between your version of `llvm-config` and `clang`. You noted that you added `C:\LLVM\llvm-new-build\Debug\bin` to your path, but that doesn't assure that the binary actually executed for each of `llvm-config` and `clang` came from the same location. If you had previously installed a canonical, pre-built binary of clang for generic compilation usage, its location will be earlier in your path than `C:\LLVM\llvm-new-build\Debug\bin`. It's unlikely that `llvm-config` was included in your pre-built binaries. The reason this matters is that if there's a mismatch between versions, the required include flags generated by `llvm-config` might not match the required include flags needed by `clang`. You can verify that execution path shadowing is not happening using `which` on Unix-like machines and `where.exe` on Windows machines after Windows Server 2003. We expect that they will both reflect that the execution path is in fact `C:\LLVM\llvm-new-build\Debug\bin`. If not, there's your problem. **I believe that this is what created the issues with options like `-wd4146` and `-wd4180`, etc.**
- **No such file or directory**: When you built LLVM, cmake detected you were building on Windows, and produced Visual Studio generator files. Meanwhile, your project appears to use some sort of GNU Make-like build system. See [here](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#usage) for more discussion of selecting generators at installation. **I believe that the mix between MSVC and another GNU Make-like build system is what created the issues with options like `/DWIN32`, `/D_WINDOWS`, `/W3`, and `/MP`.**